# Why do I get ProtocolViolationException when I do BeginGetRequestStream

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone

I am new to silverlight. I am programming in Visual Studio 2010 for Windows phone.
I try to do HttpWebRequest but debugger says ProtocolViolationException.
This my code

```
 private void log_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //auth thi is my url for request
            string auth;
            string login = Uri.EscapeUriString(this.login.Text);
            string password = Uri.EscapeUriString(this.pass.Password);
            auth = "https://api.vk.com/oauth/token";
            auth += "?grant_type=password" + "&client_id=*****&client_secret=******&username=" + login + "&password=" + password + "&scope=notify,friends,messages";
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(auth);
            request.BeginGetRequestStream(RequestCallBack, request);//on this line debager say ProtocolViolationExceptio
        }

        void RequestCallBack(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;
            Stream stream = request.EndGetRequestStream(result);
            request.BeginGetResponse(ResponceCallBack, request);
        }
        void ResponceCallBack(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;
            HttpWebResponse response = request.EndGetResponse(result) as HttpWebResponse;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string a =sr.ReadToEnd();
                MessageBox.Show(a);
            }

        }
```

Comment: You forgot to sanitize one client secret/id pair

Comment: Do somebody can give me working code for HttpWebRequest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that you aren't using POST, but GET. Try this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(auth);
request.Method = "POST";
request.BeginGetRequestStream(RequestCallBack, request);
```

Comment: @user1597524 Then you must NOT write anything in the stream. Including content in a GET request violates the HTTP protocol. It is a protocol violation. I didn't know WebRequest would throw that exception immediately (rather than let you set "POST", "PUT" etc. as the method after that and before you get the response), but I'd certainly expect a ProtocolViolationException at some point.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't even doing anything with the request stream when you get it.

`HttpWebRequest` is assuming that the reason you tried to get it, was to write content to it (the only reason for getting it, after all).

Since you aren't allowed to include content in a GET request, it realises that the only thing you can do with that stream, is something that would violate the HTTP protocol. As a tool for using the HTTP protocol, it's its job to stop you making that mistake.

So it throws `ProtocolViolationException`.

Cut out the bit about the request stream - it's only for POST and PUT. Go straight to `GetResponse()` or `BeginGetResponse()` at that point.